When selecting an inductive device in the matching circuit of RF, how to consider the self-resonant frequency of the inductor？
I want to select a series of inductor of Murata for the component of matching circuit in my UWB product(6.5GHz~8GHz) . But ,I didn't find a suitable series whose Self-resonant frequency is all bigger than 8GHz in full range of inductance. As you can see,the Self-resonant frequency of
Does the Self-resonant frequency matter in RF-matching?
Is there a recommended inductor model series?


Does the Self-resonant frequency matter in RF-matching?

Yes.  The self-resonant frequency should be higher than the frequency of operation, but by what margin depends on the application, some are less sensitive to this parameter than others.
For operation at F=8GHz, you need self-resonance to be at least 10GHz, preferably more.  The Murata LQW18AN series has afour (4) members with self-resonant frequency at 10GHz and above, refer image below:

Link for above image:
https://search.murata.co.jp/Ceramy/image/img/P02/JELF243A-0026.pdf
The Coilcraft 0402DC (1005) series has several members with self-resonant frequency at 15GHz and above, refer image below:

Link for above image:
https://www.coilcraft.com/getmedia/b3553702-9a56-4386-b513-fcddf8709240/0402DF.pdf

Thank you very much.Your suggestion means a lot  to me !

@Liamzhai  You're welcome.

@Liamzhai  If you liked my answer, an upvote would be appreciated.  :-)

At the self-resonance frequency (SRF) the inductor has lost all goods that an ideal inductor has. Do not expect that the behaviour of your circuit resembles what's expected if it's designed by assuming the inductor is ideal and you use it at frequency higher than 10...20% of the SRF. In some cases the non-ideality caused by the distributed capacitance and resistance (depends on frequency) can be taken into the account in design calculations and the result can be substantially better at frequencies higher than 20% of the SRF.
Do not use inductors which do not have specs (or proper measurements made by yourself)  Manufacturers should give s-parameters vs. frequency lists or lumped circuit models for those who know what they do — see Coilcraft's general inductor model info page.
The Kyocera's air core microwave inductor page contains download links of s.parameter table files (S2P).
At range 6.5 to 8 GHz transmission line based designs (to avoid inductors) could well be compact enough. Hopefully you also check that route.

Yes. Thanks. The S parameter is exactly what i am concerned with , because i want to use the inductor to match the impedance of antennas . Maybe i should consulting service from  the inductor supplier .

Do you know any other brand besides coolcraft that has high-frequency inductor products above 6.5GHz

Filters can be designed so that the resistive losses of the inductors are more or less taken into the account and the frequency response is still the wanted one - except the insertion loss, which can be too much in many high power transmitting or radio receiver LNA applications (several decibels).  I bet your microwave antenna matching network would be substantially less lossy if it was based on transmission line elements. About coil manufacturers: I know nothing beyond simple web searches like "microwave inductors" . Sorry.

Thank you .It's okay, your suggestion has benefited me a lot .

If an inductor is repeatable, then the exact SRF does not matter too much. You optimise the matching with that specific inductor model, and you're done.
The problem comes with getting a repeatable inductor. While the inductance and loss resistance are relatively insensitive to the build details, the self capacitance, and hence the SRF, is strongly dependent on precise wire spacing, varnish thickness etc, things that don't affect the inductance significantly. There is often very little incentive for the manufacturer to control the SRF closely, as it's not a primary specification, and 'above xGHz' is good enough for most uses.
Choosing an inductor with the SRF significantly above your frequency of interest is a way of choosing an inductor where these second order manufacturing variations should have a reduced effect on the RF response of your inductor + stray capacitance component.
In the many GHz frequency range, it can often make sense to make an inductor from a length of high impedance transmission line, which can behave more accurately like its model, even if you don't have the range of values available, or it is not as 'lumped' as you would like.
It makes a difference whether you are using the inductor for a high impedance bias-T, or for matching. When trying to obtain a high impedance, resonance is good, and as long as you can tolerate the drop in impedance at even higher frequencies, a relatively low or even in-band SRF need not be a problem. With matching, you often need an inductive component, and the above-band SRF is usually needed.

Yes , I chose the inductor as an inductive component in the RF matching circuit. It seems that I need to find a higher frequency inductor for the  matching circuit.

@Liamzhai have you considered using a length of high impedance transmission line?

Thank you for your suggestions . I have no idea about the application of high impedance transmission lines . Let me guess , the size of the high impedance transmission lines would be larger than  a 0402 inductor size . And , In practical applications, inductance values require trying different values, so it seems to be not possible to define the specifications of impedance lines .

@Liamzhai On the contrary, it is very possible to design transmission line 'inductors'. Try https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed-element_filter#Basic_components, and they simulate better than lumped components as their models are better, but yes, they will probably be bigger than 0402
